# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attributes 'extension' when trying to use HoloViews

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, holoviews

I am exploring different libraries for data visualization in Python. I recently came across HoloViews and decided to give it a shot. I installed required packages (holoviews, bokeh, param, etc.) using `pip`.

When I try to run an example from their [Introduction](http://holoviews.org/getting_started/Introduction.html), I get an error as holoviews presumably load the plotting library:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

> File "/home/tito/git/PyCode/FirstProject/holoviews/subway_stations.py", line 4, in 
> hv.extension('bokeh')
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extension'

I'm using:

- Python 3.4.5
- holoviews 1.8.1
- bokeh 0.12.6
- param 1.5.1
- ipython 6.1.0
- numpy 1.13.1
- pandas 0.20.3

If anyone could give me any hints, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've named your directory `holoviews`, it is being treated as a package, and loaded in lieu of the actual `holoviews` library. Change the name of your directory.

Comment: That was it. Thank you, @juanpa.arrivillaga !
But now I don't see plot show up after typing: 

`scatter = hv.Scatter(station_info, kdims=['services'], vdims=['ridership'])
scatter
`

I imagine I'm making another novice mistake... any idea?